# jQuery plugin function never gets reached

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with one of my jQuery plugins I'm currently working on, it never reaches the function. Now this isn't my the first plugin I have developed and I get no error, so I'm standing clueless. I've tried to log to see if the function gets reached but without success. Please help me if you know the reason.
Thanks in advance!

```
$.fn.accordion = function(options) {
    return this.each(function () {
        if (!$.data(this, "plugin_accordion")) {
            $.data(this, "plugin_accordion", new accordion(this, options));
        }
    });
};

$(".js-accordion-contact").accordion({breakpoint: "smallMedium"});
```

Comment: Have you verified that your `$(".js-accordion-contact")` has at least one element in it? Also how are you determining that it "never reaches the function"? Hopefully a breakpoint or a `console.log` statement, or something along those lines? Have you tried commenting out your whole function body and just having a `console.log`, to try to isolate the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out yesterday before going to bed, that it must be caused by a plugin name conflict, I realized that this can be the only reason, why it's not working. Somewhere else a plugin with the same name already exists. I'm using Joomla and noticed that jQuery UI has a function with the same name, so I guess After renaming my plugin I finally got it to work.